# Alguna forma de optimizar la carga en el recyclerview

Tags: android, postgresql, recyclerview, cardview

el problema es que al presionar un boton, me debe cargar unos productos (en otra activity), pero al presionarlo, se queda una pantalla en negra por un tiempo y luego de un minuto mas o menos cargan los item, los datos los saca de una BD de postgres, lo mismo pasa con los datos que tienen en el SQLite, se tarda en cargar

Lo que quisiera hacer es tener una forma para reducir ese tiempo de carga lo mas que se pueda
He estado leyendo soluciones en SO en ingles, pero han funcionado

**LISTA DE PRODUCTOS**

```
    public class Lista_Categoria extends AppCompatActivity implements Recycler_productAdapter.OnProductListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerproducto;
    private Recycler_productAdapter recycler_productAdapter;
    private List<itemproducto>product=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista__categoria);


        recyclerproducto=findViewById(R.id.recyclerlistproducto);
        recyclerproducto.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recycler_productAdapter =new Recycler_productAdapter(mostrarproductos(), this);
        recyclerproducto.setAdapter(recycler_productAdapter);
        toolbar();

        recyclerproducto.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerproducto.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        recyclerproducto.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        recyclerproducto.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

    }

    public List<itemproducto> mostrarproductos()
    {
        String categoria=getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
        String sqla="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE tipo_categoria='"+categoria+"';";
        String sqli="SELECT * FROM productos";

        Conexionpst post=new Conexionpst();
        try
        {
            Statement st =post.conexionbd().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sqla);

            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    //List<itemproducto>product=new ArrayList<>();
                    product.add(new itemproducto(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2), Float.parseFloat(rs.getString(3)), rs.getString(6),foto(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)))));

                }
            }
            st.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "lal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("MUESTRAN LOS DATOS");
        }


       /* List<itemproducto> product=new ArrayList<>();
        product.add(new itemproducto("producto 1", "1.000", R.drawable.logo));
        product.add(new itemproducto("producto 3", "3.000", R.drawable.logo));*/
        return product;
    }

  @Override
    public void onProductClick(int position) {

         final itemproducto pdpropieties=product.get(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, InterfazProducto.class);
        intent.putExtra("id_producto", pdpropieties.getId_product());
        intent.putExtra("nombre", pdpropieties.getNombre());
        intent.putExtra("precio", pdpropieties.getPrecio());
        intent.putExtra("Tipo_del_producto", pdpropieties.getTipo());
        intent.putExtra("BitImage", pdpropieties.getImgproduct());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public Bitmap foto(int id)
    {
        String sql="SELECT img FROM productos WHERE product_id="+id+";";

        InputStream im=null;

        Conexionpst post=new Conexionpst();
        try
        {
            Statement st =post.conexionbd().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                im=rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        Bitmap bpm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(im);
        return bpm;
    }
```

**RECYCLER DE LA LISTA**

```
    public class Recycler_productAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycler_productAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnProductListener mOnProductListener;
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private TextView Nombre, precio, tipo;
        ImageView FotoProducto;
        private Button delete_prod;

        OnProductListener onProductListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnProductListener onProductListener)
        {
            super (itemView);
             Nombre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Product_Name);
             precio=itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioproduct);
             FotoProducto=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageProduct);
             tipo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Unidad);

             this.onProductListener=onProductListener;
             itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onProductListener.onProductClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public List<itemproducto> productolista;

    public Recycler_productAdapter(List<itemproducto>productolista, OnProductListener onProductListener)
    {
        this.productolista=productolista;
        this.mOnProductListener=onProductListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_producto, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view, mOnProductListener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.Nombre.setText(productolista.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.precio.setText(String.valueOf(productolista.get(position).getPrecio()));
        holder.FotoProducto.setImageBitmap(productolista.get(position).getImgproduct());
        holder.tipo.setText(productolista.get(position).getTipo());

    }

    public interface OnProductListener{
        void onProductClick(int position);
    }

    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return productolista.size();
    }
}
```

No soy muy experto en android, disculpen si no me pude explicar muy bien

Comment: A parte de las recomendaciones posteadas en las respuestas de abajo. Estas invirtiendo todos los recursos del hilo principal en procesamiento. Normalmente deberías utilizar Jobs o Tareas para hacer la consulta y decodificar el stream para convertirlo a Bitmap. Esa es la razón principal por la cual te demora mucho tiempo, porque lo haces de manera síncrona, tienes que recorrer cadenas de strings gigantes codificadas para poder llevarlo a Bitmap. Intenta ejecutar tareas asíncronas por cada carga al hacer click. Te recomiendo ademas reciclarlos una vez porque se quedarán en memoria y te crasheará